# CMake cannot find Qt5Widgets on Linux Mint

Tags: cmake, linux-mint

Trying to install deepin-screenshot on Linux Mint 21 Vanessa

Got stuck at this error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:94 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5Widgets.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "Qt5Widgets", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Widgets" with
  any of the following names:

    Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
    qt5widgets-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Widgets" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5Widgets_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5Widgets" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

Have seen other questions about windows installs, but nothing that deals with Ubuntu / Mint. Looks like there isn't a package I can install, except with RPMs (e.g. red hat / suse). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got past this by doing `apt install libqt5gstreamer-dev` - which seemed to install a bunch of dependencies (I'd guess `qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools` would be the actual solve, but I'm happy enough with the dependencies I've got)

To install deepin-screenshot, I also needed:

- `apt install libqt5x11extras5-dev libdtkwidget-dev libxcb-util-dev`
- need to install https://github.com/martyr-deepin/dtkwm manually
- needed to add a line into deepin-screenshot: `src/widgets/shapeswidget.cpp` was missing a necessary `#include <QPainterPath>`

After that, deepin-screenshot installed correctly.

(Normally I would have given up by this point - but deepin-screenshot is the only self-annotating screenshot tool I've seen on linux.)